# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php

I started receiving a strange PHP error, the script was working fine on the server, but when I set up locally I get a PHP parse error but everything is looking good. The error is on this line:

```
$MaxBet = array_values($maxbet)[$Cnt];
```

From this snippet

```
$Cnt = 0;
foreach ($pcent as $val) {
    $MaxBet = array_values($maxbet)[$Cnt];
    $Payout = array_values($payout)[$Cnt];
    echo "<a href='#' id={$Cnt}>Less than {$val} Max bet:{$MaxBet} Payout:x{$Payout}</a><br>";
    $Cnt++;
}
```

Both web server and local setup using nginx and php5-fpm.

Comment: Array dereferencing is supported from PHP 5.4 onwards.

Comment: yep server php version 5.4 local 5.3!!

Comment: yep upgrade your local server

Answer (score 0):

As @mario said in the comments, you can only using array dereferencing in PHP 5.4+. Array dereferencing refers to accessing an array index directly from a function call, e.g:

```
$MaxBet = array_values($maxbet)[$Cnt];
```